# Can I connect resources from different Google Cloud accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have 2 Google Cloud accounts, `account_1` and `account_2`. On each of those accounts I created a project and I bootstrapped 2 virtual machines.

I want to know if it's possible to place those 4 machines in the same network space, to be able to communicate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using VPC network peering. The shared VPC is different because it's between an organization projects, as you have you VMs in different accounts what you have to do is VPC network peering, check this [article](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#setting_up_a_vpc_network_peering_session). After configuring on both VPCs and set the proper firewall rules you should be able to reach your 4 VMs using the internal IP, although they will not be in the same subnet but they will be able to communicate between them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at the [Shared VPC Overview documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc).

However, not all resources will be shared, you can check which ones are supported [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#resources).